# Communicating with Clips rules engine in Python

Tags: python, clips, clipspy

I would like to communicate several times with Clips rule engine in Python 3.8.3.

For example, I would like to have the following communication

1. Launch Clips

```
    C:\Users\username\Clips>"C:\Program Files\CLIPS 6.31\CLIPSDOS64.exe"
             CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
```

2. Define rules

```
    (defrule ValueManipulation
      (value ?v)
    =>
      (assert (result ?v))
    )
```

3. Query with first fact set and read results from stdout

```
    (deffacts f1 "My facts" (value 1))
    (reset)
    (run)
    (facts)
```

4. Query with second fact set and read results from stdout

```
    (deffacts f1 "My facts" (value 2))
    (reset)
    (run)
    (facts)
```

5. Exit

```
    (exit)
```

I have managed to input to stdin once and read from stdout once:

```
import subprocess

clips_commands = """
(defrule ValueManipulation
  (value ?v)
=>
  (assert (result ?v))
)
(deffacts f1 "My facts" (value 1))
(reset)
(run)
(facts)
(exit)
"""
p = subprocess.Popen('"C:\Program Files\CLIPS 6.31\CLIPSDOS64.exe"', 
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = p.communicate(input=bytes(clips_commands,'utf-8'))

for line in str(result[0]).split('\\r\\n'):
    print(line)
```

However, I would like the following kind of query several times and read the output from stdout

```
    (deffacts f1 "My facts" (value 3))
    (reset)
    (run)
    (facts)
```

Using packages like `pyclips` or `clipspy` was not preferred in the above example, because these packages were not available with `pip install`. However, repackaging one of these packages could solve the question.

Comment: It is not clear what is the issue at hand. What is the problem with the presented method? What is you are trying to achieve? What is the reason you prefer using `subprocess` instead of the libraries?

Comment: The libraries do not "pip install". Therefore I am trying to learn communicate with `CLIPSDOS64.exe`.

Comment: I just built `clipspy` for Python 3.8. You can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @noxdafox ! Reusing rules with clipspy library seems to be at least 20 times faster than the individual `CLIPSDOS64.exe` calls without reusing rules.

Comment: Edited the question to allow repackaging `clipspy` as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @noxdafox, I was able to use `clipspy` library!

Below is the test code which demonstrates reusing clips rules:

```
import clips

env = clips.Environment()

rule = """
(defrule ValueManipulation
  (value ?v)
=>
  (assert (result ?v))
)
"""
env.build(rule)

print('Add fact 1:')
env.assert_string("(value 1)")
for fact in env.facts():
    print(fact)
env.run()
print('\nResult for fact 1:')
for fact in env.facts():
    print(fact)

print('\nFacts after reset:')
env.reset()
for fact in env.facts():
    print(fact)
env.assert_string("(value 2)")

print('\nResult for fact 2:')
env.run()
for fact in env.facts():
    print(fact)

print('\nResult for fact 3:')
env.reset()
env.assert_string("(value 3)")
env.run()
for fact in env.facts():
    print(fact)
```

The above code produces the following results:

```
Add fact 1:
(initial-fact)
(value 1)

Result for fact 1:
(initial-fact)
(value 1)
(result 1)

Facts after reset:
(initial-fact)

Result for fact 2:
(initial-fact)
(value 2)
(result 2)

Result for fact 3:
(initial-fact)
(value 3)
(result 3)
```